# TOP1 in CROSS JOIN (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with child(position x, position y) and with parent(position x, position y) in sql server. What I want is to find closest parent to every child. I can do it "bad way", but probably there is a solution without using any loops.

That`s my code:

```
SELECT 
    child.idChild, child.x, child.y, 
    parent.idParent, parent.x, parent.y,
    sqrt(power(child.x - parent.x, 2) + power(child.y - parent.y, 2)) as distance
FROM 
    child
CROSS JOIN 
    parent
ORDER BY 
    idChild, distance
```

Ok, that`s fine. But now I want to limit parents only to TOP1 for each child.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A handy way to do this is with the window functions.  To get the top row, you can use either `row_number()` or `rank()`.  There is a difference when there are ties.  `row_number()` returns only one of multiple values.  `rank()` will return all of them.

Here is one way to write the query:

```
select idChild, x, y, idParent, parentx, parenty
from (SELECT child.idChild, child.x, child.y, 
             parent.idParent, parent.x as parentx, parent.y as parenty,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by child.idchild
                                order by power(child.x - parent.x, 2) + power(child.y - parent.y, 2)
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM child CROSS JOIN 
           parent
     ) pc
where seqnum = 1;
```

I removed the `sqrt()` from the distance function because it is not necessary when looking for the smallest number.